# Why does the red div not float right next to the yellow one?

Tags: css, css-transforms

I want to place the red div right next to the yellow one, **without removing anything from the code** below. It is not possible, is it? By the way, what is this behaviour called, that is caused by the transform, similar to the effect of relative positioning? It would be great to at least know how to call it, if I can't turn it off.

```css
div {
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
}
div:first-child {
  background: yellow;
  margin-left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
div:nth-child(2) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div>This is the first div.</div>
<div>2nd div.</div>
```

Comment: Uh, the effect is just called CSS transform? Not exactly sure what you're attempting to do tho.

Comment: I'm not talking about the "yellow box moves to the right by its own width" effect, but the "red box acts like the yellow was still in its original place" effect. I've heard something like the yellow "is taken out of the flow", but I'm not sure if this is the right phrase.

Comment: You are only transforming how it looks, but not its footprint in the layout. By assigning a float property you have already taken them out of the flow, so not really sure what effect you are pinning down on.

Comment: So the floating is "taking them out of the flow", but the transforming does nothing with the flow, but transforms only the rendered picture of the element instead. Do I understand it well? Then here is what I want to achieve: I want the transform to manipulate the element itself, affecting the layout directly, without leaving any footprints. Like "move the yellow box itself, not only its image".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first `div` is being transformed left by its width.  You're hoping that the second `div` can also be transformed left by the first `div`'s width, but that's not possible in CSS.

Instead, you could give the first `div` absolute positioning, and give the second `div` a 50% `margin-left`:

```css
div {
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
}
div:first-child {
  position: absolute;
  background: yellow;
  margin-left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
div:nth-child(2) {
  margin-left: 50%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div>This is the first div.</div>
<div>2nd div.</div>
```

Comment: Brilliant answer. Terry's comment was useful as well for me to understand the reason of the problem: "You are only transforming how it looks, but not its footprint in the layout.". It's bad that I can't manipulate the footprint, but fortunately you've taught me a workaround. Thanks.